# Making an ajax request from a different domain

Tags: ajax, javascript

I'm making an ajax request from my primary domain to a subdomain. I've solved my cross origin issues so I'm not getting an error. The call is returning `data:0`. I've checked my response config and the ajax url is correct as well as "action". My `functions.php` looks like this:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_sendhire", "sendhire");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_sendhire", "sendhire");

function sendhire() {

    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    return json_encode($cars);
    die();

}
```

The data, obviously, is just for testing.

Comment: `echo` doesn't change the response. The will eventually process data being passed to it not return anything. Maybe a success/error message but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Admin-Ajax to output the content, you should use `echo` instead. There is nothing to be viewed when you use `return`, so you'll get a `0`.

This quotation from the codex explains further about the `0` response:

> If the Ajax request fails in `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, the response
>   will be -1 or 0, depending on the reason for the failure.
>   Additionally, if the request succeeds, but the Ajax action does not
>   match a WordPress hook defined with `add_action('wp_ajax_(action)',
>   ...)` or `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)', ...)`, then
>   `admin-ajax.php` will respond 0.

Now, if you are going to output a JSON response, you should take a look into the REST API. Its default response type is JSON.

To do so, register a path for the endpoint, and create a callback function:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'dcp3450', '/test_endpoint/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'sendhire' 
    ) );
});

function sendhire() {

    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    return $cars;

}
```

Now by accessing `http://example.com/wp-json/dcp3450/test_endpoint/` you will get your JSON response, and you can get rid of this annoying 0 that is following humanity to its end.

Comment: I'm using the REST API for the site currently to pull data using WP as a headless cms. I'm attempting to use the ajax call to process a form.

Comment: I've tried your code, and it works with `echo`, but outputs `0` with `return`. The Admin-Ajax must echo the content if you are trying to send it to the browser.

Comment: I wonder if there is an issue with me making a call to a subdomain?

Comment: I can't tell since you didn't include any details about that. But to mention again, you will always get the `0` if you return the data, since there is nothing to be displayed.

Comment: I changed `return` to `echo` but I still get 0.

Comment: Then there's a problem with calling the function as you mentioned, since I tried your code by accessing `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=sendhire` and it worked fine for me, outputting the array.

Comment: I changed my function to send send a test email. Running it directly sends the email but calling it via the ajax request doesn't. I assume there may be a cross domain thing happening here but I don't get an error...

Comment: What happens if you access the URL (like I posted in my comment above) directly? Does it send the email?

Comment: Yes, running it directly sends the email.

Comment: Then there is 100% chance that you have a problem in your Ajax call or cross domain. Your Ajax hook works fine.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress have a very useful API (REST API) for this work, you can use it, instead of sending ajax request.
Here is the documentation have a look please https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/